# How can I convert VARIANT type from Snowflake to array of struct on Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, snowflake-connector

I have the table below on Snowflake. myarray column is VARIANT type in a json format:

[image]

I'm retrieving that table on Spark using the Snowflake Spark connector:

```
val mydf: DataFrame = spark.read
.format("snowflake")
.options(options)
.option("query", "SELECT uid, myarray FROM mytable")
.load()
```

The issue is that myarray comes as string. Non-convenient data type for my purpose.

I'd like to get to the point where I can retrieve index and value as struct type:

```
df.select("uid", "myarray.index", "myarray.value")
```

Do you know what's the best way to apply a schema to myarray column without losing its position against the other columns(uid)?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I write dataframe with an column of type array of int, the snowflake connector then will create a table with a column of type Variant in Snowflake.

Then, when I read this table with the snowflake, I've got exactly to same issue. Snowflake Variant type is mapped to String.

I've found a solution by mapping the dataframe using Sparks from_json function. Apparently, the data inside a column of type Variant is json by default.

Following code works for me:

```
spark.read
      .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
      .options(sfOptions)
      .option("dbtable", tableName2)
      //.schema(schema1) // original schema doens't match
      .load()
      .withColumn("NUM", $"NUM".cast(IntegerType))
      .withColumn("ARR", from_json($"ARR", ArrayType(IntegerType)))
      .withColumn("MAP", from_json($"MAP", MapType(StringType, IntegerType)))
      .withColumn("OBJ", from_json($"OBJ", StructType(Array(StructField("STR", StringType, nullable = false)))))
```

Comment: I decided to flatten the columns directly from the Snowflake query using LATERAL FLATTEN

Answer (score -1):

is there a way to do it without the passing column names

```
.withColumn("NUM", $"NUM".cast(IntegerType))
      .withColumn("ARR", from_json($"ARR", ArrayType(IntegerType)))
      .withColumn("MAP", from_json($"MAP", MapType(StringType, IntegerType)))
      .withColumn("OBJ", from_json($"OBJ", StructType(Array(StructField("STR", StringType, nullable = false)))))
```

Comment: Wait, this sounds like a question, even though you posted it as an answer. Does this code work…? If so, please [edit] your answer to make that clear.